# "bash: rbenv: command not found"
and "bash: nodenv: command not found"

Tags: raspbian, debian, node.js, bash, ruby

After trying to install [this](https://github.com/mislav/dotfiles) script using these commands:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/mislav/dotfiles.git ~/dotfiles 
$ ~/dotfiles/script/bootstrap
```

I restarted my Raspberry Pi and I'm seeing these errors on my terminal everytime i open:

```
bash: rbenv: command not found
bash: nodenv: command not found
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you see a folder `~/.rbenv` - ? if not, then the bootstrap failed to do what it purports to do - also, when you ran bootstrap, were there any errors?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `~/.profile` now contains these two commands. These belong to a javascript and a ruby environment. If you want to use these, install them and your `command not found` will disappear.

If you do not want to use ruby or node.js, have a good look at your `.profile`. Do not just delete these two commands. Your set-up for dot files does some things that you did not expect, so there may be other surprises as well.